# MongoError: "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $where cannot be applied to a field"

Tags: mongodb

My mongo collection has below record

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("58c1c1712031fd38e4a30ce1"),
    "name": "TEST",
    "grpName": "TEST",
    "lookupType": "TEST",
    "keys": {
        "TIER": ".*Gold.*",
        "WLAN_Location": "UseCase_Tier_WLAN",
        "TGPP_Location": "UseCase_Tier_TGPP"
    },
    "version_key": NumberLong(7),
    "_transId": "8cea9a7e-1759-4016-9c65-2d043ae0605e-5"
 }
```

I am firing

```
"db.dmtl_TEST.find({"keys.TIER":{$where:"Gold".match("keys.TIER")}})"
```

query but getting

> error code 17287 with message as "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue
>   $where cannot be applied to a field".

I am using $where to match regex value stored in mongo record. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This should work. `db.dmtl_TEST.find({$where:"'Gold'.match(this.keys.TIER)"})`

Comment: Thank you Veeram, it worked.

Comment: Why I get syntax error while trying to match your answer with my example: `data = db['WDIData'].find({'_id': 0, 'Country Name': 1, $where:"'Indicator Name'.match(ind)"}, year: 1})`. Can't find any documentation nowhere.